# Passing arguments to PhantomJS through WebDriver/GhostDriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I've been trying to get PhantomJS ( 1.9.7 )/GhostDriver to be initialized with some custom settings for quite a while, but have been completely unsuccessful.  I'm using wd.js as my WebDriver library, and I have tried just about every combination of properties that I can think of, however nothing has worked, and I haven't been able to find any documentation.

Here's what I have tried passing ( userAgent shortened for sanity, it's a real one in my actual test cases ):

`{ browserName: "phantomjs", "userAgent": "foo" }`

`{ browserName: "phantomjs", "settings": { "userAgent": "foo" } }`

`{ browserName: "phantomjs", "page": { "userAgent": "foo" } }`

`{ browserName: "phantomjs", "page": { "settings": { "userAgent": "foo" } } }`

`{ browserName: "phantomjs", "phantomjs": { "page": { "userAgent": "foo" } } }`

`{ browserName: "phantomjs", "phantomjs": { page": { "settings": { "userAgent": "foo" } } } }`

And lot's more actually, using just about every combination of keys that I could think of from https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver#what-extra-webdriver-capabilities-ghostdriver-offers .

Does anyone have any idea what you need to pass in order to customize settings in PhantomJS when using Webdriver/Ghostdriver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh, well this was very unintuitive.  When the documentation says that the property is `phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent`, one would expect that it follows normal javascript conventions.  Not so, the key is LITERALLY `phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent`, so the answer to my question is:

```
{
    "browserName": "phantomjs",
    "phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent": "foo"
}
```